# Destroying object without its ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating LIKE model to my rails application. Routing is:

```
resources :bonuses, only: %i(index create) do
  resources :likes, only: %i(create destroy)
end
```

I did a create of like and now trying to make a dislike button.
I want to delete like with this button:

```
= link_to "Dislike", bonus_like_path, method: :delete
```

But i get error here: **missing required keys: [:bonus_id, :id]**
If I pass the bonus_like_path(bonus) I will miss the ID parameter of like(but I dont need him, I know user.id)

To delete like everything that I need to know is **bonus_id** and **current_user.id**

**schema.rb** (likes)

```
create_table "likes", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "user_id",  null: false
  t.integer "bonus_id", null: false
  t.index ["user_id", "bonus_id"], name: "index_likes_on_user_id_and_bonus_id", unique: true, using: :btree
end
```

The associations are simple:

**Bonus**:

```
has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
has_many :liked_users, through: :likes, source: :user
```

**User:**

```
has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
has_many :liked_bonus, through: :likes, source: :bonus
```

**Like:**

```
belongs_to :bonus, counter_cache: true, touch: true
belongs_to :user
```

So I understand that I can make DELETE `bonus_like_path(bonus)` request because user already defined in `current_user`. But don't know how to write it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You could put an `unlike` method on bonus controller in this case.  It's not RESTful, but since you're not passing the like id in the first place the bonus id seems to be the one id you need and the right place to take action.

```
def unlike
  bonus = Bonus.find(params[:id])
  bonus.likes.where(:user_id => current_user).destroy_all
  # render or redirect
end
```

and in routes

```
resources :bonuses, only: %i(index create) do
  put :unlike, on: :member
  resources :likes, only: %i(create)
end
```

If you go this way, move the `like` method over too and remove the likes resources in routes.

Answer (score 0):

Just because you pass id params in doesn't mean you have to use those specific params. In your view you could do:

```
link_to "Dislike", bonus_like_path(bonus, like.id), method: :delete
```

and in your controller:

```
current_user.likes.where(bonus_id: params[:bonus_id]).destroy_all
```

or whatever you need to do to destroy that object. The point is that like you said, you have `current_user` in your controller.

Just because you pass in a bonus id and like id, doesn't mean you have to act on those params specifically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're trying to piggyback on the existing resourceful path helpers to get a link to delete your like BUT without sending the like id which is generated by the Resourceful route. I don't know why you aren't using the REST-like(no pun intended) like id, but Instead of finding a way of ignoring the like id parameter, how about setting up a proper route that requires only the bonus id?

```
resources :bonuses, only: [:index :create] do
  resources :likes, on: [:create]
  delete 'delete_like', on: :member
end
```

With this you should have a `/bonuses/1/delete_like` route, and a `delete_like_bonus_path`helper that will receive the bonus id as `:bonus_id` parameter (Check with rake routes). More info at the routing guide [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions). Tested it on rails 3.2.